# Implementing winapi(SendInput) with dart:ffi

Tags: c++, winapi, dart, ffi

I'm trying to implement the [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function in dart using ffi.
It requires an unsigned integer, an array of input and an integer.
I'm finding difficult to implement the INPUT array structure, this is what I've done so far:

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

import 'user32.dart'; //import dylib

typedef SendInputC = Uint32 Function(
    Uint32 cInputs, Pointer pInputs, Int32 cbSize);

typedef SendInputDart = int Function(int inputCount, Pointer inputs, int size);

int SendInput(int type, {MouseInput mi, KeyboardInput ki, HardwareInput hi}) {
  final SendInputP =
      dylib.lookupFunction<SendInputC, SendInputDart>('SendInput');

  var input = Input.allocate(
      type: type,
      mi: mi?.addressOf ?? nullptr,
      ki: ki?.addressOf ?? nullptr,
      hi: hi?.addressOf ?? nullptr);

  var result = SendInputP(1, input.addressOf, sizeOf<Input>());
  return result;
}

class Input extends Struct {
  @Uint32()
  int type;

  Pointer<MouseInput> mi;
  Pointer<KeyboardInput> ki;
  Pointer<HardwareInput> hi;

  factory Input.allocate(
          {int type,
          Pointer<MouseInput> mi,
          Pointer<KeyboardInput> ki,
          Pointer<HardwareInput> hi}) =>
      allocate<Input>().ref
        ..type = type
        ..mi = mi
        ..ki = ki
        ..hi = hi;
}

/// MouseInput struct
class MouseInput extends Struct {
  @Int32()
  int dx;

  @Int32()
  int dy;

  @Uint32()
  int mouseData;

  @Uint32()
  int dwFlags;

  @Uint32()
  int time;

  @Uint32()
  int dwExtraInfo;

  factory MouseInput.allocate(
          {int dx = 0,
          int dy = 0,
          int mouseData = 0,
          int dwFlags = 0,
          int time = 0,
          int dwExtraInfo = 0}) =>
      allocate<MouseInput>().ref
        ..dx = dx
        ..dy = dy
        ..mouseData = mouseData
        ..dwFlags = dwFlags
        ..time = time
        ..dwExtraInfo = dwExtraInfo;
}

class KeyboardInput extends Struct {
  @Uint16()
  int wVk;

  @Uint16()
  int wScan;

  @Uint32()
  int dwFlags;

  @Uint32()
  int time;

  @Uint32()
  int dwExtraInfo;

  factory KeyboardInput.allocate(
          {int wVk = 0,
          int wScan = 0,
          int dwFlags = 0,
          int time = 0,
          int dwExtraInfo = 0}) =>
      allocate<KeyboardInput>().ref
        ..wVk = wVk
        ..wScan = wScan
        ..dwFlags = dwFlags
        ..time = time
        ..dwExtraInfo = dwExtraInfo;
}

class HardwareInput extends Struct {
  @Uint32()
  int uMsg;

  @Uint16()
  int wParamL;

  @Uint16()
  int wParamH;

  factory HardwareInput.allocate(
          {int uMsg = 0, int wParamL = 0, int wParamH = 0}) =>
      allocate<HardwareInput>().ref
        ..uMsg = uMsg
        ..wParamL = wParamL
        ..wParamH = wParamH;
}
```

but calling the `SendInput` function doesn't produce any effect and returns 0, for example this code sends no mouse input.

```
  var mi = MouseInput.allocate(dx: 505, dy: 175, dwFlags: 0x0002);
  var r = SendInput(0, mi: mi);
```

this is how the function looks like in C++

```
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx = 505;
    input.mi.dy = 175;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    input.mi.time = 0;


    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
```

the `tagInput` struct contains unions which seems like they are not yet supported ( https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38491 ), but I was wondering if there's a workaround to this till the unions are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will not work since your struct is just too big. What you really want is the allocated memory have the same size as in regular C version (which is 28 bytes), so something like this:

```
class KeyboardInput extends Struct {
  @Uint32() int type;
  @Uint16() int virtualCode;
  @Uint16() int scanCode;
  @Uint32() int flags;
  @Uint32() int time;
  Pointer dwExtraInfo;
  @Uint32() int _padding;
}
```

With that being said - it still does not work, and I don't really know why. I've even [experimented](https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/e55k23/problem_with_dart_ffi_and_winapi/) with passing just raw byte array pointer which still didn't work in dart (in C it worked all right). This may be a bug in dart FFI itself, but can be a lot of other stuff. I'm trying to crack this as I also need this to work.

For now you can use the deprecated function that just works:

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';
DynamicLibrary _user32 = DynamicLibrary.open("user32.dll");

typedef _keybd_event_C = Void Function(Uint8 bVk, Uint8 bScan, Uint32 dwFlags, Pointer dwExtraInfo);
typedef _keybd_event_Dart = void Function(int bVk, int bScan, int dwFlags, Pointer dwExtraInfo);
var keybd_event = _user32.lookupFunction<_keybd_event_C, _keybd_event_Dart>("keybd_event");

const MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0;
typedef _MapVirtualKeyW_C = Uint32 Function(Uint32 uCode, Uint32 uMapType);
typedef _MapVirtualKeyW_Dart = int Function(int uCode, int uMapType);
var MapVirtualKeyW = _user32.lookupFunction<_MapVirtualKeyW_C, _MapVirtualKeyW_Dart>("MapVirtualKeyW");


void main() {
  keybd_event(
    0x5a, 
    MapVirtualKeyW(0x5a, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), 
    0, 
    nullptr);
}
```

PS:
Also if you need more functions from WinAPI you can use my [quickly stitched together dart binding generator](https://dartpad.dev/452866084ca49d27f3d52543d5574989) for WinAPI functions. You just run it and paste the WinAPI function in the upper textarea and the bottom area should show the dart binding. Sometimes it is missing some type definition (just add another type `Mapping`), but for the most part it works quite well :) (does not work for structs tough)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, actually I should've updated the answer, I tried using the correct structure of 28 bytes, but it didn't work. I asked in the dart repo for [help](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38491#issuecomment-568932746), but I didn't quite understand how I should make my structure. In the end I've used mouse_event and keybd_event, which just work fine ( [here](https://github.com/Hexer10/dart_winapi/blob/master/lib/src/user32/mouse_event.dart)). Also thanks for the binding generator, that might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in [dart library called `win32`](https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/win32-library.html) that includes [SendInput](https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/SendInput.html), which OP already uses. That library also includes definition of [INPUT](https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/INPUT-class.html) which can be used without needing to declare it internally.

However, I found that binding that whole library just for this functionality was a bit of an overkill, so extracted the required code as follows:

```dart
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;

import 'dart:io'; // For sleep
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

//// declare INPUT
// from: https://github.com/dart-windows/win32/blob/main/lib/src/structs.g.dart
base class KEYBDINPUT extends ffi.Struct {
  @ffi.Uint16()
  external int wVk;
  @ffi.Uint16()
  external int wScan;
  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int dwFlags;
  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int time;
  @ffi.IntPtr()
  external int dwExtraInfo;
}

base class HARDWAREINPUT extends ffi.Struct {
  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int uMsg;
  @ffi.Uint16()
  external int wParamL;
  @ffi.Uint16()
  external int wParamH;
}

base class MOUSEINPUT extends ffi.Struct {
  @ffi.Int32()
  external int dx;
  @ffi.Int32()
  external int dy;
  @ffi.Int32()
  external int mouseData;
  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int dwFlags;
  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int time;
  @ffi.IntPtr()
  external int dwExtraInfo;
}

base class INPUT extends ffi.Struct {
  @ffi.Uint32()
  external int type;
  external _INPUT__Anonymous_e__Union Anonymous;
}

// Make sure your INPUT class includes all three types of input, even if you use only one of them
sealed class _INPUT__Anonymous_e__Union extends ffi.Union {
  external MOUSEINPUT mi;
  external KEYBDINPUT ki;
  external HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

extension INPUT_Extension on INPUT {
  MOUSEINPUT get mi => this.Anonymous.mi;
  set mi(MOUSEINPUT value) => this.Anonymous.mi = value;
  KEYBDINPUT get ki => this.Anonymous.ki;
  set ki(KEYBDINPUT value) => this.Anonymous.ki = value;
  HARDWAREINPUT get hi => this.Anonymous.hi;
  set hi(HARDWAREINPUT value) => this.Anonymous.hi = value;
}

//// declare SendInput function interface
// from: https://github.com/dart-windows/win32/blob/main/lib/src/win32/user32.g.dart
final _user32 = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open('user32.dll');
final _SendInput = _user32.lookupFunction<
    ffi.Uint32 Function(ffi.Uint32 cInputs, ffi.Pointer<INPUT> pInputs, ffi.Int32 cbSize),
    int Function(int cInputs, ffi.Pointer<INPUT> pInputs, int cbSize)>('SendInput');

int SendInput(int cInputs, ffi.Pointer<INPUT> pInputs, int cbSize) =>
    _SendInput(cInputs, pInputs, cbSize);

//// If you just want to use Dart's built-in SendInput instead, ignore all code above this point and uncomment the following line:
// import 'package:win32/win32.dart';


//// Application code
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
const int INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;
const int VK_SPACE = 0x20; // Spacebar key

void main() {
  sendInput(VK_SPACE);
}

int sendInput(int virtualKeyCode) {
  // Allocate memory for two INPUT structures (key down and key up).
  final inputs = calloc<INPUT>(2);

  // Key Down
  inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inputs[0].ki.wVk = virtualKeyCode;
  inputs[0].ki.time = 0;

  // Key Up
  inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  inputs[1].ki.wVk = virtualKeyCode;
  inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  // Send the key down event
  SendInput(1, inputs.elementAt(0), ffi.sizeOf<INPUT>());

  // Small delay
  sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

  // Send the key up event
  int result = SendInput(1, inputs.elementAt(1), ffi.sizeOf<INPUT>());

  calloc.free(inputs);
  return result;
}
```

For reference, Windows API docs for [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) and [INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input)

The small delay is there to ensure the input gets registered correctly. You may not need it in your application.

---

*Note: I'm new to Dart at the moment, hence I wouldn't know how to fix the code posted in the original question. However, the method I share successfully utilises the `SendInput` function that the OP seems to want to use, hence leaving it here hoping it will help.*

Comment: *"The small delay is there to ensure the input gets registered correctly."* - That's a creative interpretation of the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), completely invalidating the whole purpose of using `SendInput()`. At that point, you could just as well call the (broken) [`keybd_event()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) API if you trust your opinion that this was somehow more *"correct"*.